# Put derivatives function in separate file for use with solve_ivp?

Tags: python, function, scipy

Is it possible to put the callable function containing the ODE derivatives (dydt equations) to be solved using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp in a separate Python file? Doing so would reduce the size of the main program and make it a lot easier to create structured programs that include solution of ODEs.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is possible to put any Python function in a separate file. All you need to do is import them appropriately to your main file.

Comment: Dear Sunessh: Thanks very much for your kind reply. I was able to import the derivatives function into the main program that calls solve_ivp and it worked fine. A related question, if I may: I would like to be able to share a number of global variable among all files and functions. In FORTRAN the easiest way to do this is to create a module (e.g. titled "globvars" that is then "used" within all the subroutines, functions, etc. that require the global variables. Is there a convenient way to do this in Python? Many thanks for any help you can provide, Eric

Comment: No worries, I figured out the problem!

Comment: Hi Eric, sorry for the delay in my reply. If you want all the variables to be globally accessible/synchronisable, you can declare all the variables in global mode. For example, you can declare `global a` in order to declare the variable `a` in global mode. (Or, if you want a function to access the values of global variables without declaring them as global variables, you can pass `globals()` as an argument to your function, which would be of `dict` type with keys as variable names and values as the corresponding values, from which you can access the value of the required variable.)